# iOS: Animation is effecting my other ViewController for some odd reason

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation

I do not know why my NewViewController is getting my ViewController's animations. Everything in my NewViewController.xib is acting strange.For example, my UITableView is popping in with an ease in animation as well as other objects. I checked my NewViewController and it is NOT hooked up with my ViewController. If you have any suggestions on how to stop this I will appreciate it.

ViewController.m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];
 [self start];
  }

 -(void)start{
CGContextRef *imageContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:imageContext];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
image.alpha = 1;
image1.alpha = 1;
[self performSelector:@selector(change) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
  }


 -(void)change{
  NewViewController *newViewController = [[NewViewController alloc]init];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:NO];
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new view controller is pushed during an animation from view controller. Thus, it is not surprising that you get results that affect the new controller. You will need to move your new view controller creation and presentation out of the animation.

Also, I do not see where you call `[UIView commitAnimations]` to properly finish the animation block.

Also, you are calling interface animations in `viewDidLoad` when maybe the view is not even visible yet, again with unpredictable results. Instead, you should be calling initial animations in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: The commitAnimation seems to fix everything. Thanks, did not see that method in the tutorial I followed.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, how is your NewViewController springing into existence?

It sounds like you have a nib file set up for it, but are then calling it in your code with init, as opposed to initWithNibNamed.

It also sounds like you may have included an instance of NewViewController from within your navigationController's nib as well, although I can't quite tell if that's the case from your statements.

To summarize, it looks like you may be using 2 or 3 different ways to create an instance of NewViewController, when you only need to do it once.

I'll go out on a limb and assume that you'd like to use the custom designed NewViewController.xib file that you've made. If so, you'd want to do this:

1. Make sure there are no ViewController objects in your navigation controller with a class of NewViewController.
2. You don't technically have to add a property or instance variable to your class of type NewViewController, since the navigationController will take over the retain count once you push, but there's a really good chance you'll want to have the NewViewController scoped to your class anyway to handle events later / reuse, etc...
3. When you create an instance of NewViewController, instantiate it from the nib like this (note I've assumed you've declared @property (strong, nonatomic) NewViewController* nvc;)

-

```
nvc = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"nameOfNibGoesHereWithoutAppendingDotXib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Now when newViewController loads, you should see it behaving like you laid out in your Nib.

I made a lot of assumptions here, feel free to correct and re-direct your question as needed, and we'll try to help!